# How to merge two ArrayList<Map<String, String>> to one?

Tags: java, hashmap, multimap

`ArrayList<Map<String, String>> result1`

`result1` is like

```
(1, a)
(2, a)
(3, b)
(4, e)
(5, e)
```

`ArrayList<Map<String, String>> result2`

`result2` is like

```
(1,android)
(2,ios)
(3,android)
(4,android)
(5,ios)
```

I want to merge the two maps to build a map like this one

```
(1, ( a, android))
(2, ( a, ios))
(3, ( b, android))
(4, (e, android))
(5, (e, ios))
```

How to make this happen?

Comment: Show what you've tried already.

Comment: 1) Create your own class with the two fields (e.g. for `a` and `ios`) 2) Create a new list `result3`, 3) Iterate over `result1` and `result2` at once, 4) Create objects of your class with the values from the lists your iterating and add them to your new list `result3`

Comment: What is `ArrayList` doing here?

Comment: I've tried creating a multimap using Google guava library

Comment: I'm using arraylist just because I only can retrieve the data from database in the form of Arraylist<Map>

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Yes!! Exactly!

Comment: I see this as a `ArrayList<Pair<Integer,String>>`, why would you complicate with maps?

Comment: @DavidW "_I only can retrieve the data from database in the form of Arraylist<Map>_" what kind of library/framework are you using?.. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge two streams with `Stream.concat()` and group them with `Collectors.groupingBy()` and `Collectors.mapping()`:

```
Map<String, String> first = Map.of("1", "a", "2", "a");
Map<String, String> second = Map.of("1", "android", "2", "ios");
Map<String, List<String>> result = Stream.concat(first.entrySet().stream(), second.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())));
System.out.println(result);
```

will output:

```
{1=[a, android], 2=[a, ios]}
```

Comment: `first` and `second` (or `result1` and `result2`) are supposed to be an `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko true, however OP also states "I want to merge the two maps to build a map like this one" which contradicts the `ArrayList` part.

Answer (score 0):

For the requirement you have specified here, you can do it like this.

I'm iterating over the keys of the first map. And collecting values for each key from all the maps and putting them in a list. Then put the list to the resulting map.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MergeMaps
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("1", "a");
    map1.put("2", "a");
    map1.put("3", "b");
    map1.put("4", "e");
    map1.put("5", "e");

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("1", "android");
    map2.put("2", "ios");
    map2.put("3", "android");
    map2.put("4", "android");
    map2.put("5", "ios");

    Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
    keys.addAll(map1.keySet());
    keys.addAll(map2.keySet());

    Map<String, List<String>> mergedMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : keys)
    {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(map1.get(key));
      list.add(map2.get(key));
      mergedMap.put(key, list);
    }

    System.out.println(mergedMap);
  }
}
```

Output will be:

`{1=[a, android], 2=[a, ios], 3=[b, android], 4=[e, android], 5=[e, ios]}`

Comment: This isn't a complete answer. What if there's an entry `map2.put(6, "windows")` that isn't in map1?

Comment: @BenR., thanks for pointing it out. I edited the answer and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach as well:

```
Map<String, String> result1 = new HashMap<>();
// initialize result1 ...

Map<String, String> result2 = new HashMap<>();
// initialize result2 ...

Map<String, Map<String, String>> mergedResult = new HashMap<>();
```

**Up to Java 8**

```
result1.forEach((k1, v1) ->
            mergedResult.put(k1, new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put(v1, result2.get(k1));
            }}));
```

**Java 9 or later**

```
result1.forEach((k1, v1) -> mergedResult.put(k1, 
                                 Map.of(v1, result2.get(k1))));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way arriving at the result:

**Input Data**:

```
// The first list of data
List<Map<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(getMapData("1", "a"));
list1.add(getMapData("2", "a"));
list1.add(getMapData("3", "b"));
list1.add(getMapData("4", "e"));
list1.add(getMapData("5", "e"));
list1.add(getMapData("999", "x"));
System.out.println(list1);
```

Data 1: `[{1=a}, {2=a}, {3=b}, {4=e}, {5=e}, {999=x}]`

```
// The second list of data
List<Map<String, String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(getMapData("1", "android"));
list2.add(getMapData("2", "ios"));
list2.add(getMapData("3", "android"));
list2.add(getMapData("4", "android"));
list2.add(getMapData("5", "ios"));
list2.add(getMapData("888", "zzzzz"));
System.out.println(list2);
```

Data 2: `[{1=android}, {2=ios}, {3=android}, {4=android}, {5=ios}, {888=zzzzz}]`

```
// utility method for creating test data
private static Map<String, String> getMapData(String k, String v) {
    Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put(k, v);
    return m;
}
```

---

**The Result Process**:

The output is stored to a `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();

// process the first list
for (Map<String, String> m : list1) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
        valueList.add(entry.getValue());
        result.put(entry.getKey(), valueList);
    }
}

// process the second list; merge with the first
for (Map<String, String> m : list2) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        String k = entry.getKey();
        List<String> valueList = result.get(k);
        if (valueList == null) {
            valueList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        valueList.add(entry.getValue());
        result.put(k, valueList);
    }
}

System.out.println(result);
```

*The Result*:

```
{1=[a, android], 2=[a, ios], 3=[b, android], 4=[e, android], 5=[e, ios], 888=[zzzzz], 999=[x]}
```